# Ansible playbook not running for localhost also, how to fix this?

Tags: centos, ansible, centos8

I am running ansible on centos machine

```
[ansadmin@ansible docker]$ ls
Dockerfile  hosts  simple-devops-image.yml  webapp.war
[ansadmin@ansible docker]$ cat hosts
localhost
```

simple-devops-image.yml

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: true

  tasks:
  - name: stop current running container
    command: docker stop simple-devops-container
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: remove stopped container
    command: docker rm simple-devops-container
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: remove docker image
    command: docker rmi simple-devops-image
    ignore_errors: yes

  - name: build docker image using war
    command: docker build -t simple-devops-image .
    args:
      chdir: /opt/docker
  - name: create container using simple image
    command: docker run -d --name simple-devops-container -p 8080:8080 simple-devops-image
```

Even on localhost I am getting permission denied.The user is already with sudo rights.

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts simple-devops-image.yml --check

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansadmin@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

ping is working.

```
[ansadmin@ansible docker]$ ping localhost
PING localhost(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `ssh` connection for the `localhost`.

Just update your `hosts` file to include `ansible_connection=local` for `localhost`

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

Also, make sure you are not overriding `ansible_connection` to `ssh` anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this failed is that you weren't telling Ansible to ask for a password, and you hadn't yet set up SSH keys.

Your `ssh-copy-id` command copies your SSH key to the target host (in this case, the box you're on) and installs it so that password-less SSH works.

**Another way** to get this to work would be to add the correct flags to the playbook command:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -k`

or if you need a sudo password as well:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yml -bkK`

- The `-k` asks for a password ('key') for the SSH user
- The `-b` tells ansible to elevate to a privileged user (defaults to using sudo)
- The `-K` asks for the password with which to elevate.

Answer (score 1):

running below command fixed the issue.

```
ssh-copy-id ansadmin@localhost
```